# Message de Aguarde ao clicar no botão de salvar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui

Olá, senhores estou com dificuldades de colocar uma mensagem de Aguardando para o usuário quando ele clicar no botão salvar e ficar esperando o retorno do servidor. Estou usando Jquery Dialog e Partial View para carregar um html do servidor dentro de uma div. Alguém tem uma ideia?

```js
 $("#NovoDialog").html("").dialog("option", "title", "Novo").load("/Teste/Create", function () { $("#NovoDialog").dialog("open"); });

  $("#NovoDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false, width: 520, height: 550, modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Salvar": function (evt) {
                        var buttonDomElement = evt.target;
                        $(buttonDomElement).attr('disabled', true);
                        if ($("#FormCadastro").validate().form()) {
                            $.post("/RegistroAcaoCorretiva/Save",
                                $("#FormCadastro").serialize(),
                                function (data) {
                                    if (data.success) {
      
                                        $("#NovoDialog").dialog("close");
                                        location.reload();
                                      
                                    } else {        
                                        $("#NovoDialog").html(data);
                                           $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#NovoDialog"));
                                    }
                                });
                        } else {
                            $(buttonDomElement).attr('disabled', false);
                        }
                    },
                    Cancelar: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                }
            });
```

```html
  <div id="progressbar">
    <h2>TESTE</h2>
      <div id="NovoDialog" title="" class="Hidden"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente faço assim:

```
    $('form').on('submit', function () {
        $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true).text("Aguarde...");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false).text("Salvar");
        }, 10000); // Aqui você define quantos milissegundos a tela deve aguardar.
    });
```

Isto é para o botão de salvar, mas a lógica para uma mensagem modal, por exemplo, é a mesma.

Comment: Obrigado Cigano dessa forma funciona.